# No "hamburger" icon for DrawerLayout when Toolbar is set from Fragment

Tags: android, material-design, androiddesignsupport

I am using Android Design Support Library to get navigation drawer pattern. I have following main activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/pl.dzielins42.skinflint.android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/view_nav_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The `container` layout is where I inflate my fragments. Some of the fragments have `Toolbar` in their layouts. I use navigation drawer to move between these fragments. In each of the fragments with `Toolbar` I set it as activity's actionbar using `setSupportActionBar`, and later

```
supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
supportActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

The problem is that on the first fragment (inflated in activity's `onCreate`) the "*hamburger*" icon is displayed properly, but after I change the fragment to another fragment with `Toolbar`, the icon changes to standard back-arrow.

I have tried to fix it by using `ActionBarDrawerToggle` (v7) and calling `syncState` in `onDrawerClosed`. This fixes it partially, as the "*hamburger*" icon is set but only after drawer is fully closed, so while it is still closing, back arrow-icon is visible.

Can someone provide better solution?

Answer (score 0):

set the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` properly:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
```